# Complex matrix similar to a matrix with identical diagonal entries

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a complex matrix. Show that it is similar to a matrix with identical diagonal entries.

I do have some sense, but could not prove it.

Comment: @daw $A$ is similar to, for example, 
$$
\frac 12 \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is equivalent to show that if $A$ is a matrix with trace $0$, then there is a similar matrix whose diagonal entries are all zero.

We prove that this is the case inductively, using Lemma 2 from [this paper](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/trace0.pdf), which states that if $A$ is not a non-zero scalar multiple of the identity, then there is a similar matrix with a $0$ as its first diagonal element (the paper contains a proof).

**Base case:** $A$ is $1 \times 1$

Trivially, $A = 0$ if its trace is zero.

**Inductive step:** if $A$ is $n \times n$, then it is similar to a matrix of the form
$$
\pmatrix{0&r^T\\c&A'}
$$
We note that $A'$ has a trace of zero.  By our inductive hypothesis, there is some $B = SA'S^{-1}$ with zeros on the diagonal.  Define 
$$
S_0 = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&S}
$$
we have
$$
S_0\pmatrix{0&r^T\\c&A'} S_0^{-1} = 
\pmatrix{0&r^T S^{-1}\\Sc & SA'S^{-1}} = 
\pmatrix{0&r^T S^{-1}\\Sc & B}
$$
By the transitivity of similarity, we conclude that $A$ is similar to a matrix with $0$s along the diagonal, as desired.

---

Here's how we extend this to the general case: Given a matrix $A$, let $a = \text{trace}(A)/n$.  Let $B = A - a I$.  Note that $B$ has a trace of zero, so we may state that $B$ is similar to a matrix $B' = SBS^{-1}$ with $0$s on the diagonal.

Define $A' = SAS^{-1}$.  We have
$$
A' = SAS^{-1} = S(B + aI)S^{-1} = SBS^{-1} + aI = B' + aI
$$
Thus, all the diagonal entries of $A'$ are $a$.  So, $A$ is similar to a matrix with identical diagonal entries.

Comment: Can you prove, please, the first affirmation of the inductive step? Thank you!

Comment: The first... "affirmation"? Not sure what you mean

Comment: if A is n×n, then it is similar to a matrix of the form (...) .

Comment: Okay, by "affirmation", you mean proof. It's in the paper that I linked in my answer

Comment: Oh! I didn't read all those things. Thank you!